# how to set ng-class with multiple "OR" condition

Tags: angularjs, if-statement, ng-class

I have to set color based on coming details from angular list.

In below code coming data is in string so I have set condition with string

**CODE:**

```
<td ng-class="{IsGreen: s.InformationForm == 'Form Completed'  || IsMaroon: s.InformationForm == 'Fill Form'}">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-if="s.InformationForm == 'Form Completed'" class="IsColorWhite">{{s.InformationForm}}</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-if="s.InformationForm == 'Fill Form'" class="IsColorWhite">{{s.InformationForm}}</a></td>
```

Above is code I have done but not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
<td ng-class="{IsGreen: s.InformationForm == 'Form Completed', IsMaroon: s.InformationForm == 'Fill Form'}">
```

It doesn't need an `either-or` statement in there.

Clearly stated in the [AngularJS Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

Comment: But it will set both the class I want to set only one from the condition either it will be IsGreen or IsMaroon or from etc conditions...

Comment: It will set `IsGreen` if `s.InformationForm == 'Form Completed'` and `IsMaroon` if `s.InformationForm == 'Fill Form'`

Comment: No you got me wrong I want only one from the condition not both. Want only "OR" not "AND"

Comment: What DGarvanski's written is an 'OR' relationship since your model 's.InformationForm' can contain one string at a time.

Comment: @3rules you focused on the _and_, not on the _if_ in my comment, I guess...

Comment: @DGarvanski I understand you comment but as per your answer you have set "," and it is used for set multiple classes not to set a single from the conditions. I may have more than values coming in the condition and from that too many conditions I want only one. Ok let me try

Comment: No it's not. It's multiple classes if both conditions are `true`, which isn't possible in your case.

Comment: No it is taking first value always

Comment: It worked today. Actually don't know the reason why it was not worked yesterday nothing change but it's working today may be kind of issue cache clear may be not sure any way thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ternary operator like

```
<td ng-class="s.InformationForm == 'Form Completed'?'IsGreen':(s.InformationForm == 'Fill Form'?'IsMaroon':'')">
```

Comment: Yes it should be something like this but not working it always takes first value I mean IsGreen

Comment: let me check that , but you make sure if `s.InformationForm` is correct , by printing it on page by `{{s.InformationForm}}`

Comment: there may a chance that data is not updated when you need it to be

Comment: Thanks @Viplock for your answer as well

Comment: great , this ans will be useful when the condition with if else will increase. cheers